# UIImagePickerController subclass for video recording increases height of window of the application by 20 pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

As shown in the image, the UIImagePickerController subclass is being dismissed. It creates that red color on top which can't be explained why and after it is dismissed, the application window is pushed down by 20 pixels.

[image]

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? The same subclass works fine when being used to capture an image and not video.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh dude I faced this issue some days before. After dismissing `UIImagePickerController`,Status bar just come out,it becomes visible(no more hidden).And about red color I think your set background color for previous view is **red** color.

So just override method to hide status bar in controller where you are pushing/dismissing `UIImagePickerController` view.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I have not set red color anywhere. The above solution does not work.